# Create an empty list of lists in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create in python a list that inside has 3 lists, each of them have 2 vectors of 4 elements, something like that:

```
[[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]], 
 [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]], 
 [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]
```

This is just a simple example but I would like to automate it in order to be able to create an object like that with a much higher number of elements.

I tried to do it the following way:

```
grid=[np.zeros((2,4)) for x in range(3)]
grid
```

However when I print it the result is something like this instead

```
[array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])]
```

The structure should be fine, but I don´t know if the fact that it says array is normal or I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the problem so ?

Comment: this is a list of `np.array` not list of lists; they behave similarly and depending on what you want to do, it might be the correct approach. You can see some of the differences in terms of memory allocation [here](https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Confused: If you are already using numpy for your project, and you want to create this kind of "rectangular" structure where everything is the same size at a given level of nesting... then why do you want to produce a list of lists (of lists...) instead of a numpy array?

Comment: Why not `np.zeros((3,2,4), int)`?  Add `tolist()` to make a list of lists of lists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It's pretty basic, it's all over the place, and I can't see it ever being useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here a list of `2D np.array`, if you want a `list` of `list` of `lists` :

```
grid = [[[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)]
```

The following will build the same structure, but each sublist will be copy, so unusable (see [List of lists changes reflected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)
)

```
grid = [[[0] * 4] * 2] * 3
```